# google_font license (Apache2.0) has no Copyright what to do?

Tags: license-notice, source-code, license-file

I'm currently programming an app with flutter and have already listed all the licenses I use from the packages on an individual license page in the Settings.

I also used the `google_font` package.
Unfortunately I noticed that the developers of the license did not add a copyright notice to this one using the Apache 2.0 license. I always add the license as a whole with an appendix. At the beginning there is a passage that says

> Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]
>
> Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
> you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
> You may obtain a copy of the License at
>
> ```
>    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
> ```
>
> Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
> distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
> WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
> implied.    See the License for the specific language governing
> permissions and    limitations under the License.

**Unfortunately, this has not been filled out. Can I simply list the license no copyright notice?**

[The whole license I am listing](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts/license)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Section 4(c) lists the only obligations you have with regards to copyright notices:

> You must retain, in the Source form of any Derivative Works that You distribute, all copyright, patent, trademark, and attribution notices from the Source form of the Work, excluding those notices that do not pertain to any part of the Derivative Works;

If there are zero of such notices to retain, then retaining zero such notices fully satisfies this requirement.

If there is a `NOTICE` file then you must reproduce that as well, per 4(d), but in this case, there does not appear to be any `NOTICE` file either.